# In this code javascript validation is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

How it will work? I want to know how javascript connect with html and div tag is correct. I didn't get which code is doing mistake.

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">

     function validate()
     {
      if (document.myForm.name.value="") {
       alert("should be fill");
       document.myForm.name.focus();
       return false;
      }
      return(true);
      }
      

    </script>
```

```css
.container{background-color:gray;
width:550px;
height:650px;
align-content:center;
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);}

h1{text-align:center;
color:darkslategray;
text-decoration-line:underline;}

input{width:100%}

#button{text-align:right;}

body {background-image:url("bg1.jpg");
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
 <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css\bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css\custom.css">
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
 <title>
  login form
 </title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
   <form method="post" name="myForm" onsubmit="return(validate());" data-toggle="validator">
    <div class="form-group">
     <h1><b><u>
      Create an account
      </u>
     </h1>
     
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-6">
        First Name:
        <input type="text" name="name" id="" value="" placeholder="First Name">
        
        <span id="fnameerror" class="text-danger">
        </span>

       </div>
       <div class="col-md-6">
        Last Name:
        <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" >
        <span id="lnameerror" class="text-danger">
        </span>
       </div>  
      </div>
     <br>
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12">
       Company Name:
       <input type="text" name="companyname" id="" placeholder="Company Name">
       <span id="" class="text-danger">
        </span>
       </div>
      </div>
     <br> 
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12">
       Street address:
       <input type="text" name="streetaddress" id="address" placeholder="Street address">
       <span id="adderror" class="text-danger">
        </span>
       </div>
      </div>
     <br> 
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12">
       Town/City:
       <input type="text" name="city" id="city" placeholder="Town/City">
       <span id="cityerror" class="text-danger">
        </span>
       </div>
      </div>
     <br> 
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12">
       State/Country:
       <input type="text" name="state" id="state" placeholder="State/Country">
       <span id="stateerror" class="text-danger">
        </span>
       </div>
      </div>
     <br> 
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12">
       Postcode/Zip:
       <input type="text" name="zip" id="zip" placeholder="Postcode/Zip">
       <span id="ziperror" class="text-danger">
        </span>
       </div>
      </div>
     <br>
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-6">
        Phone:
        <input type="text" name="Phone" id="phone" placeholder="Phone">
       <span id="pherror" class="text-danger">
        </span>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-6">
        Email:        
        <input type="emaill" name="Email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
       <span id="emailerror" class="text-danger">
        </span>
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-1">
       <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="box" placeholder="">
       <span id="boxerror" class="text-danger">
        </span>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-11">
        Create an account
       </div>  
      </div>

      <div class="row" id="button">
       <div class="col-md-12">
        <button type="submit" value="submit">
         <b>SignUp</b>
        </button>
       </div> 
      </div>
    </div>
   </form>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using assignment operator in  `if (document.myForm.name.value = "")`

Try with this code

```
 function validate() {
    if (document.forms["myForm"]["name"].value == "") {
      alert("should be fill");
      document.myForm.name.focus();
      return false;
    }
    return (true);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed equals to `==` in your comparison. For comparison is should be `==` double equals. Change it and it should work.

```
if (document.myForm.name.value == "") {
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you haven't added the js file in the html file. Add the js file just above ending the body tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="location to the file"><script>
```

Moreover in update the js code with:

```
function validate(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(document.myForm.name.value);
    if (document.myForm.name.value == "") {
      alert("should be fill");
      document.myForm.name.focus();
    }
  }
```

You also need to modify the form element.

```
<form method="post" name="myForm" onsubmit="validate(event);" data-toggle="validator">
```